# 16x2 Character LCD on Altera Cyclone V GT Dev kit using VHDL and I2C

Tags: vhdl, fpga, i2c, lcd, intel-fpga

I am trying to familiarize myself with the Cyclone V FPGA, I have an Cyclone V GT Dev kit. The Dev kit comes with a 16x2 character LCD (NHD-0216K3Z-NSW-BBW-V3). The LCD is connected to the FPGA via I2C theres only 2 connections SDA and SCL by default. I'm just trying to make it do anything, but nothing happens.

I've written some code in VHDL and have used ModelSim and SignalTap for debugging. Everything seems to be ok, but nothing happens. The LCD displays Not Connected from power up and nothing changes. The process at the end is just for a clock to use on SignalTap for sampling.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity LCD_1 is
    port (
        dsw     : in    std_logic;
        clk_50M : in std_logic;
        led     : out std_logic;
        i2c_scl : out std_logic;
        i2c_sda : inout std_logic
    );
end entity; 

architecture Behavioral of LCD_1 is

    component PLL is
        port (
            refclk  : in std_logic;
            rst     :   in std_logic;
            outclk_0 : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal clk_5M       : std_logic;
    signal clk_50k      : std_logic := '0';
    signal sig_i2c_scl  : std_logic := '1';
    signal sig_i2c_sda  : std_logic := '1';
    signal routine      : integer := 0;
    signal ack          : std_logic := '0';
    signal ack_returned : std_logic := '0';
    signal bounce       : std_logic := '0';
    signal data         : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal rst          : std_logic := '0';
    signal clk_10M      : std_logic;

begin

    PLL_Please : component PLL
        port map(
            refclk => clk_50M,
            rst => rst,
            outclk_0 => clk_10M
        );


    process(clk_50M) 
        variable count : integer range 0 to 1000;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_50M) then
            case count is
                when 1000 => clk_50k <= not clk_50k;
                            count   := 0;   
                when others => count := count + 1;               
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;    

    process(clk_50M)
        variable state : integer range 0 to 1000;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_50M) then    
            if dsw = '0' then   
                case state is
                    when 1000   => bounce   <= '1';
                    when others => state    := state + 1;
                end case;
            else
                bounce <= '0';
                state  := 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    data             <= x"50" when routine = 0 else 
                         x"FE" when routine = 1 else
                         x"70";
    i2c_scl          <= sig_i2c_scl;
    i2c_sda          <= sig_i2c_sda when ack <= '0' else 'Z';
    ack_returned     <= i2c_sda;


    process(clk_50k, bounce)
        variable state : integer range 0 to 13;
        variable index : integer range 7 downto 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_50k) then
            if bounce = '1' then
                case state is
                    when 0 => sig_i2c_sda <= '0';
                                 state := 1;

                    when 1 => sig_i2c_scl <= '0';
                                 state := 2;

                    when 2 => sig_i2c_sda <= data(index);
                                 state := 3;

                    when 3 => sig_i2c_scl <= '1';
                                 if index = 0 then
                                    state := 5;
                                 else   
                                    state := 4;
                                 end if;

                    when 4 => index := index - 1;
                                 state := 1;

                    when 5 => index := 7;
                              state := 6;

                    when 6 => sig_i2c_scl <= '0';
                                 state := 7;

                    when 7 => ack <= '1';
                                 state := 8;

                    when 8 => sig_i2c_scl <= '1';
                                 state := 9;

                    when 9 => state := 10;

                    when 10 => sig_i2c_scl <= '0';
                                  if ack_returned = '1' then
                                        state := 2;
                                  elsif routine < 2 then    
                                        routine <= routine + 1 ;
                                        state := 2;
                                  else  
                                        state := 11;
                                  end if;
                                  ack <= '0';

                    when 11 => state := 12;
                    when 12 => sig_i2c_scl <= '1';
                                  state := 13;  
                    when 13 => sig_i2c_sda <= '1';  
                end case;
            else
                sig_i2c_scl <= '1';
                sig_i2c_sda <= '1';
                state := 0;
                ack <= '0';
                routine <= 0;
                index := 7;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(clk_10M)
        variable counter : integer range 0 to 2000;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_10M) then    
            case counter is
                when 1000 => counter := counter + 1;
                                 led <= '1';
                when 2000 => led <= '0';
                                 counter := 0;  
                when others => counter := counter + 1;
            end case;
        end if; 
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Can you show the signaltap log for transaction beginning?

Comment: https://ibb.co/b7MGQQs here's a link for a snippet of SignalTap. I can't embed the image yet because I'm a new contributor. Here's a link to the LCD datasheet: http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-0216K3Z-NSW-BBW-V3.pdf . On page 7 there's a table of commands.

Comment: The start condition and address looks correct. Either the display has address altered (the spec say it's possible), or the pins assignment could be wrong.

Comment: Vlad you are amazing!!!!! One of my pin assignments were incorrect. It's working now. Thank you, much appreciated!!!